# Css includes not working while implementing modrewrite in PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I am working on wamp.
the link to my site is : localhost/tshirtshop/

Before rewriting it is : localhost/tshirtshop/index.php?product=12

After rewriting it is : localhost/product-title-p12

**Problem:**
Everything is working fine. but the problem is with Css files.

This file is not including.. when i saw the source code (Ctrl+U) the path is like this :

localhost/tshirtshop/product-title-p12/styles/tshirtshop.css

**What i tried:**

I tried this

```
<style>
    <?php include 'styles/tshirtshop.css';
   </style>
```

It works but not a solution for me. as there are some other images to be included also i.e logo
which results as this path:
   localhost/tshirtshop/product-title/images/tshirtshop.png

It might be a very easy solution. But i am facing problem since one hour. i tried googling for similar problems but not found any. so please dont mind. and sorry for my english.

Comment: would you please show the link tag for css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use absolute path like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/tshirtshop/styles/tshirtshop.css" />
```

Comment: thanks.i used this. ` <link rel="stylesheet" href="localhost/tshirtshop/styles/tshirtshop.css" type="text/css">` It is working but will it be a problem when users access site by example.com or www.example.com or htt p: //example.com ?

Comment: make the css path value in config file

Comment: @Abrar Yes it will. You'll have to go and change all those `localhost/` to the `example.com/` or create a config file that holds the value for it.

Answer (score 1):

CSS isn't included in PHP like a typical server script, it's linked via HTML rendered by the client's web browser.

So instead of this:

```
<style>
    <?php include 'styles/tshirtshop.css';
</style>
```

Try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/tshirtshop.css">
```

Comment: using this path it becomes: localhost/styles/tshirtshop.css. Not even working for homepage.

Comment: An absolute URL (starting with a slash) begins its search in your document root. Whatever folder your server is looking at when you visit "localhost/", put tshirtshop.css in "styles/tshirtshop.css" relative to that location and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should avoid using relative paths for css and js. Only full paths will do the trick for you if you use seo urls with Apache's mod_rewrite. So this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
```

on page

```
http://www.mypage.com/seo-url
```

searches for a css file in:

```
http://www.mypage.com/seo-url/theme.css
```

that does not exist. While this:

```
http://www.mypage.com/theme.css
```

is what you want. So use right from the very start:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.mypage.com/theme.css">
```

and you are done. Same with js.

Comment: thanks.i used this. 
`
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/tshirtshop/styles/tshirtshop.css" type="text/css">`

It is working but will it be a problem when users access site by example.com or www.example.com or http://example.com ?

Comment: You should use the default format like `http://www.mypage.com` for the full urls. If your server is set to redirect properly `http://mypage.com` to `http://www.mypage.com` then you will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I Can't tell exactly what the issue is without looking at your `.htaccess` file (<sup>*If you could include that we can help you debug further*</sup>).
But I'd warrant a guess that it just has a `RewriteRule` ?

What you should include before your rewrite rule is something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Your rewrite rule here...
```

There are other options aswell. You could specify a `<base>` in your HTML markup. [<sup>*- Read More*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)

That would look like this:

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/">
```

Which would allow you to use relative paths like you are currently doing. Your other option would be to do as the other answers have stated, but who wants to go through all their code and re write all of that stuff again?